# Bind net device (adapter) to an application

Tags: linux, sockets, raw-sockets

I have an Ethercat master, which is using a linklayer based on a linux socket. I started my test and I can see that to send one frame I need up to 43us.
I tried now to stress the net devices using

**stress-ng --class network --all 1**

Now the transmission of one frame needs up to 300-400us, which is rather a bad performance for a linklayer.
Is there a way to bind this net device to my application so that no other applications can use the net device I am using?